# Changing the context/binding/scope of a ruby block (Rails-specific form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, form-for

```
def form_helper(record, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  form_for(record, *(args << options.merge(:builder => builder))) do |f|
    f.hidden_field 'hidden', 'key'
    yield &block
  end
end
```

If I have this helper, how would I change the scope of the block passed in so it would be evaluated within the context of `f`?

So I could use it like:

```
<%= form_helper @resource, :builder => SomeFormBuilder do |form| %>
   Some stuff
<%- end %>
```

But it would output the hidden field and whatever else was in the block. Since I'm only adding hidden fields, I don't want to create a custom form builder, but rather specify a different form builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this was to call the block like so: `block.call(f)` and use concat for the other fields.

```
  form_for(record, *(args << options.merge(:builder => builder))) do |f|
    block.call(f)
    concat hidden_field_tag 'key', "#{key}/${filename}"
    concat hidden_field_tag 'AWSAccessKeyId', "#{access_key}"
    concat hidden_field_tag 'acl', "#{acl}"
    concat hidden_field_tag 'success_action_redirect', "#{redirect}"
    concat hidden_field_tag 'policy', "#{policy}"
    concat hidden_field_tag 'signature', "#{signature}"
  end
```